# Axis tick numbers overlap in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The following code can be used to create a TikZ plot:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
     view={0}{90},
     scale only axis,
     width=\linewidth,
     height=0.839628\linewidth,
     xmin=40000, xmax=140000,
     ymin=2e+008, ymax=2.03e+008,
     axis on top,
     legend style={nodes=right}]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My output is this:

[image]

The "2" and the "0.4" overlap. How can I fix this?

Comment: You could specify `xtick={50000,60000,70000,80000,90000,100000,110000,120000,130000,140000},`. This is a bit manual, but it does work. Perhaps someone else will have a better idea

Comment: You could shift the `xticklabels` down a bit with `xticklabel shift={.1cm}` as an argument to the `axis`, would that be acceptable?

Comment: Both are good suggestions which work! Thanks! If you add them as answers we can mark this question as resolved.

Comment: There is another problem with this chart: values on the y-axis are apparently degenerate due to the precision formatting. Adding `yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=3}` (cannibalised from [this nabble thread](http://old.nabble.com/Disabel-the-scientific-number-format-td26557323.html)) seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could shift the `xticklabels` down a bit by adding `xticklabel shift={.1cm}` as an argument to the `axis` environment. This moves all the `xticklabels` away from the axis by the specified length. There is (naturally) a similar command for the y-axis, `yticklabel shift={<dimension>}`, as well as a command that affects all axis, `ticklabel shift={<dimension>}`. From section 4.14.2 *Tick Alignment: Positions and Shifts* in the manual (for v. 1.5.1, dated Dec 29, 2011).

Close up screenshot of the difference:

[image: without xticklabelshift][image: with ticklabelshift]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
     view={0}{90},
     scale only axis,
     width=\linewidth,
     height=0.839628\linewidth,
     xmin=40000, xmax=140000,
     ymin=2e+008, ymax=2.03e+008,
     axis on top,
     legend style={nodes=right},
     xticklabel shift={.1cm}]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

One way is to specify your `xtick`s so that

```
xtick={50000,60000,70000,80000,90000,100000,110000,120000,130000,140000}
```

Note that you can't do

```
xtick={50000,60000,...,140000}
```

as the numbers are too big to handle.

Ideally I would have found a solution that was less manual, but I'm usually prepared to make the effort if the end result is good :)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
scale only axis,
width=\linewidth,
height=0.839628\linewidth,
xmin=40000, xmax=140000,
ymin=2e+008, ymax=2.03e+008,
xtick={50000,60000,70000,80000,90000,100000,110000,120000,130000,140000},
axis on top,
legend style={nodes=right}]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```