# Overlapping axis labels on tikz-pgf axis

Tags: pgfplots, axis

This may be similar to some other questions (for example: [Axis tick numbers overlap in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46793/axis-tick-numbers-overlap-in-tikz)), but different enough that the solutions do not seem to work.

Here is a basic example of the issue:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
  \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}     %for graphics
   \pgfplotsset{compat = newest}     %to run newest version
  \begin{document} 
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
     xmin=-10, xmax=42, ymin=-6000, ymax=46000,
     axis lines=middle, 
     xtick = {-8,-4,...,40},
     ytick = {-4000,0,...,44000},scaled y ticks = false,
     xlabel = \(x\),
     ylabel = \(y\)
   ]
   \addplot[
      domain=0:32,
      samples=20,]{32000-1000*x};
       \addlegendentry{\(32000-1000x\)}
   \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

The bottom left numbers are overlapping and I can not seem to get them to stop. I want to avoid any significant rescaling as this is an example to help students understand graphing a function.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Hi, is the `myaxis` style necessary to demonstrate the problem? If yes, you need to provide that style :) If not, just as well remove it from the code.

Comment: It was not and I removed. Sorry about that. I had just realized I left it in and was coming to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: How would you like the solution to look like? It is easy to remove one of the numbers.

Comment: Sorry about the missing begin document. Something weird happened when I tried to edit it and it double copied and then I deleted too much when I fixed it. To the question of what I want it to look like, I want the labels of the tick marks there but not overlapping. I am not sure how else to describe it. Perhaps shrinking their size?

Comment: I have a possible fix by including ticklabel style={font=\tiny} in the axis options. However, this requires still playing around with the plot dimensions. It seems like setting the axis to middle should cause tikz to automatically adjust the tick marks to avoid this overlap problem and doing it manually is going to be very time consuming. Perhaps there is a better fix?

Answer (score 1):

> I want the labels of the tick marks there but not overlapping. I am
> not sure how else to describe it.

As you are not able to describe what you want, here is a solution, where you can change size and position as you want. No amount of adjustment will make it less than awful though.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}     
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-10, xmax=42, ymin=-6000, ymax=46000,
axis lines=middle, 
xtick={4,8,...,40},
extra x ticks={-8,-4},
ytick={0,4000,...,44000}, scaled y ticks=false,
extra y ticks={-4000},
xlabel=\(x\), ylabel=\(y\),
extra x tick style={xticklabel style={yshift=2pt, font=\scriptsize}},
extra y tick style={yticklabel style={yshift=-1pt, font=\scriptsize}},
]
\addplot[
domain=0:32,
samples=20,]{32000-1000*x};
\addlegendentry{\(32000-1000x\)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph where tick labels do not overlap]